# Where can I find Protoc.exe from Google protocol buffer?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I just downloaded latest Google protocol buffer, but I am unable to find protoc.exe that I need to compile .proto file. All I see are source files. Do I have to build the same using sources? I have protoc.exe from older version 2.6.1. Not sure how I got it though.